# Products in cart reports magnto2 backend

Tags: magento2.3, reports, magento-2-commerce

When i go to reports -> products in cart i am getting price 0 and product name blank.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reindexing Magento2?  Go to the cli and type: php bin/magento indexer:reindex then try again.

Comment: Yes i did but its same @seanbreeden